# How to include lib.es2015.core.d.ts in tsconfig.json?

Tags: typescript, tsc, typescript-typings

I'm writing Angular 2 Universal app, so I don't want any DOM types.
But I want to compile all files in dir, so setting `"file"` in `tsconfig.json` is not acceptable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> But I want to compile all files in dir, so setting "file"

`file` has no effect on `lib.d.ts` anyways.

> lib.es2015.core.d.ts in tsconfig.json

If you want `core` you would do:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es5","es2015.core"]
}
```

## More

More : https://github.com/basarat/typescript-book/blob/master/docs/types/lib.d.ts.md#lib-option

However you most likely want to include all of `es6` and not just `core` or `array` etc.:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es6"]
}
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mark my own answer as accepted.
BTW, is there any way to import types from lib?
I want something like `import { Document as DOMDoc } from 'dom.d.ts';` because I have my own type named `Document`

Answer (score 1):

typescript@>2.0

```
"compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "lib": ["es5", "es6", "es6.array"]
}
```

Comment: `Error:TS5024:Compiler option 'lib' requires a value of type list.` with typescript 2.2.1

Comment: @AT GH issue  updated
`Space will not be allowed as a separator. This rule apply to both command line and tsconfig`

Comment: @OwnageIsMagic This was a proposal version for `tsconfig.json`, to just make the lib property with a string, but it got rejected (which is for the best) and the proper notation is to use an array: `["es5", "es6", "es6.array"]`